# DiscordJS V12 client.guilds.cache.get(...).emojis.forEach is not a function

Tags: discord.js, emoji

```
  let static = [], animated = [];
  client.guilds.cache.get('911491194654175242').emojis.forEach(emoji => emoji.animated ? animated.push([emoji.id, emoji.name]) : static.push([emoji.id, emoji.name]));

  console.log('Static Emojis\n');
  static.forEach(emoji => console.log('<:' + emoji[1] + ':' + emoji[0] + '>'));
  console.log('\nAnimated Emojis\n');
  animated.forEach(emoji => console.log('<a:' + emoji[1] + ':' + emoji[0] + '>'));
```

This is my code for my ready event, I am trying to log all the emojis in my guild to the console to make my life easier but returns an error `client.guilds.cache.get(...).emojis.forEach is not a function`

Comment: You missed another `cache`. `emojis` is a manager, so you'll need: `client.guilds.cache.get('x').emojis.cache.forEach()`

Comment: Also just fyi, you can get to the emojis here as well `client.emojis.cache`